# How to post new JMS Messages asynchronously after processing an inbound Message?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, message-driven-bean

We have a scenario where, after processing an incoming message A with a Message-Driven Bean, we write a follow-up message B to another queue. We are using Glassfish 3.1.

One goal in this case is that posting message B can take place asynchronously, and does not need to be reliable - meaning, if after processing message A we attempt to post message B and it fails, we do not roll back the processing for message A.

A second goal is that posting message B should not block or extend the scope of the transaction covering message A. We would like the transaction covering message A to be closed as soon as possible and not be held open while message B is being processed.

One idea is to  create a special EJB with a method marked @Asynchronous for this purpose, and looking up and invoking that EJB at the end of onMessage(). We're not sure if that is the best practice in this case, however.

We aren't interested in bringing in an extra orchestration solution (e.g. ESB) that would handle this and more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

My understanding is that MDB's are in their own transactions. So a problem with B isn't going to roll A back. This should be the default behavior.

Comment: We have two problems we are trying to address. First, we don't need the transaction for processing message A in onMessage() to cover anything we do with message B. We also don't want any exceptions that occur in processing message B to escape and cause message A to roll back. That part we can take care of by being careful with exception handling. The second problem is that we want message A to be processed as soon as possible, and any resources (e.g. db) released as soon as possible, so we'd like to send message B outside of the transaction covering message A.

Comment: You want to separate the sending of the message or the consumption of the message? Are you saying you want A to submit B but you don't want the submission to be part of A's transaction? If so, why?